# Need to PIVOT data from table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table, unpivot

I have a sql table called BasketTable which has data like

```
Assists  Rebounds   Steals  Blocks  Fouls   TeamId
10        32          8       6      11       13
18        36          8       6      9         9
```

I want output like this

```
StatsName    Team1   Team2
 Assists      10      18
 Rebounds     32      36
 Steals        8       8
 Blocks        6       6
 Fouls        11       9
```

If there is 3 row in example then in output third team data column would be added

I'm trying this query for that

```
select StatsName, HomeTeam from 
(
select Assists, DefensiveRebounds as Rebounds, Steals, Blocks, PersonalFouls as Fouls
from CombinationStatistics cs
where GameId = 1082960
) x
 unpivot (
    HomeTeam for StatsName IN (Assists, Rebounds, Steals, Blocks, Fouls)
 ) p
```

Above query give me this output,

```
StatsName   HomeTeam
Assists       10
Rebounds      32
Steals         8
Blocks         6
Fouls         11
Assists       18
Rebounds      36
Steals         8
Blocks         6
Fouls          9
```

I know that's wrong, I want another column for second team, right now it comes in one column. How to differentiate data by TeamId?

Comment: So...what's your question / problem? Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15 yet?

Comment: You're going to need to both unpivot and pivot here. If you have an indeterminate number of team, that's going to be some real "messy" dynamic SQL. I would urge that this isn't something to do in SQL in your not familiar with it. Seems like something for your presentation layer to do; such as a matrix in SSRS or a Pivot table in Microsoft Excel.

Comment: You need to add `TeamID`. That's all!

Comment: I've added TeamID, but its not working @MaciejLos

Comment: That's isn't "all" @MaciejLos . The OP will need to then pivot their unpivoted data, and even then, it'll only handle 2 teams, for 2+.

Comment: @Larnu, i wasn't enough specific. Sorry. I've added my answer, according to your comment.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for a specific number of teams, in this case 2. It won't, however, return more columns if you have more teams. That is because the only way to do that is with Dynamic SQL, and honestly, unpivoting, and then pivoting dynamically is messy and not something you should be doing in SQL. That is a job for the presentation layer.

```sql
WITH RNs AS(
    SELECT Assists,
           Rebounds,
           Steals,
           Blocks,
           Fouls,
           TeamId,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY TeamID DESC) AS RN
   FROM dbo.YourTable),
Unpvt AS(
    SELECT RN.RN,
           V.StatName,
           V.StatNumber
    FROM RNs RN
         CROSS APPLY (VALUES('Assists',RN.Assists),
                            ('Rebounds',RN.Rebounds),
                            ('Steals',RN.Steals),
                            ('Fouls',RN.Fouls))V(StatName,StatNumber))
SELECT U.StatName,
       MAX(CASE U.RN WHEN 1 THEN StatNumber END) AS Team1,
       MAX(CASE U.RN WHEN 2 THEN StatNumber END) AS Team2
FROM Unpvt U;
```

Certainly, if you don't understand the above, you should not be going down the dynamic approach, as you'll have no hope of being about to support it; and it's you that will need to support it not the community on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

As @Larnu mentioned, you need to unpivot data and pivot them again. See:

```
SELECT StatsName, [9], [13]
FROM
(
  SELECT TeamId, StatsName, HomeTeam
  FROM
  (
    SELECT 10 Assists, 32 Rebounds, 8  Steals, 6 Blocks, 11 Fouls, 13  TeamId
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 18 Assists, 36 Rebounds, 8  Steals, 6 Blocks, 9 Fouls, 9  TeamId
  ) pvt
  unpivot
  (
    HomeTeam for StatsName IN (Assists, Rebounds, Steals, Blocks, Fouls)
  ) unpvt
) src
pivot(SUM(HomeTeam) for TeamId IN([9], [13])) final
```

[db_fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5f1fc30738d654f43ea878ac683f582f)